# how to solve no date entry above 2019 with out sysdate

Tags: oracle

[image: calendar date]

As seen on above picture, I have one date entry field and one pick date button that opens calendar.

Now I want to set a trigger that prevents user from entering date greater than 01.01.2019 and raise error that

> You cannot enter date greater than 01.01.2019

but I do not want to use system date as user can change system date and than enter data.

Comment: If 2019-01-01 is fixed, how does `sysdate` make a difference here? And by the way, ordinary users should not have the right to tamper with the time settings of a server. Fix that.

Comment: thanks for solving this problem by property pallete method, i was stuck for days to find a proper trigger. so in my case db 9 server and client is running is on same machine so according to u db return date so if we change windows date will this impact db server date also ?

Comment: Yes; the database will take date/time information from the operating system of the database server.

Comment: @IPlayGames - you again? ))) I try explain again. You use the year portion of SYSDATE ONLY to compare today's year with 2019-01-01 and build your logic around it. How else would you know what year is today??? You compare 2018- the sysdate year with 2019. That was my answer to your previous post. And this is duplicate by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by saying that "user can change system date"? This is Oracle Forms, right? SYSDATE returns the database server system date, not client (i.e. user's own PC) date, so - go on and use SYSDATE, no problem with that (unless, of course, users have access to the database server, but that's another story & a huge security hole).

By the way, apart from using a trigger (that would be the WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM), a simpler way to do that is to open item's Property Palette and use the "Highest allowed value" property, set to *today*.